# Save a SVG of JUST what is showing

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, svg

I have to admit that I'm a newbie to Illustrator. (Bezier curves I've never got!) I have a design that I'm preparing for laser cutting and it needs it in EPS/SVG. I see the Save as SVG option but its saving the whole file (i.e. all my layers*) - not just what is showing. Is the only way to do it to Print to a postscript file and convert from that??

Seems a bit nuts

- I realise now that layers in Illustrator is not like photoshop!

Comment: Use eps and say no editing capabilituies and it will flatten your work. You can then reload it and make svg if you like.

Answer (score 1):

I can assume that if you are laser cutting that the intent is to make some sort of an outline of whatever it is you created (i.e you don't need various layers and colors). In that case, you don't need to perform any sort of magic to create a single layer svg, you just need to combine the shapes using the pathfinder tool and then export as svg-

This is the easiest way to combine all the layers into one layer and avoid any svg compression trickery.